# CompilationRelaxatinos and SecurityPermissons

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I am not `C#` specialist, just a student enthusiast. I have code:

```cs
using System;
public class C {
    public static void M(Action a) {
        var r = __makeref(a);
        var b = __refvalue(r, Action);
        b();
    }

    static void WriteHello() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }

    public static void Main() {
        M(() => WriteHello());
    }
}
```

After placing that code in [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgZgAIMiBhIgbzyNpONUwhKiIFkAKR9IgQwEoqNOiIBuvAE5EpAXiIB9eQFteAawCmE9QDMOAgNzCRtcVOBE5irdvEAbAK7qOEmCUzp+h3MbrAOnoyIAX0DAxmZUVgB1CQBLABd1AAl1W1sAe38hbx83AE4OACIUtPSAQkKAnNoQ6qIw9B5qOpFOLJkAPiIYhOTUjP8qkVqgoA=) I noticed some interesting attribute, precisely:

```
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
```

What are they for? As far as I know from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilationrelaxationsattribute.compilationrelaxations?view=netframework-4.8) for `CompilationRelaxations`:

> Gets the compilation relaxations specified when the current object was constructed.

What does `when` mean? And for [SecurityPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.securitypermissionattribute?view=netframework-4.8):

> SkipVerification: Gets or sets a value indicating whether permission to bypass code verification is declared.

I couldn't find what does what exactly `SecurityAction.RequestMinimum`. Can somebody answer me?

Comment: "current object" means the [CompilationRelaxationsAttribute] object, the *when* is when the assembly is loaded by the CLR.   This is pretty obscure compiler spew, I think it tries to say that the assembly doesn't use interned strings and doesn't require any special CAS permissions.  This helps optimize the loading of the assembly.  CAS is obsolete, don't waste your life on it.